# Why am I getting an attribute_methods error when using form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I keep getting this error when I attempt to do this form_for, either in a partial or in the "show" view.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Showing c:/.../show.html.erb where line #1 raised:

```
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:272: syntax error, unexpected ')'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:273: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting $end
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
2:   <div class="field">
3:     <%= f.text_area :content %>
4:   </div>
```

At this point, my controller only has this:

```
def show  
     @post = Post.new  
end
```

And my view only has:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>  
  <div class="field">  
    <%= f.text_area :content %>  
 </div>  
 <div class="actions">  
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>  
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

My model is:

```
# == Schema Information  
#  
# Table name: posts  
#   
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key  
#  content    :string(255)  
#  approved?  :boolean  
#  kid_id     :integer  
#  created_at :datetime  
#  updated_at :datetime  
#  
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :kid  
  attr_accessible :content  
  validates :content, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 140 }  
  validates :kid_id, :presence => true  



default_scope :order => 'posts.created_at DESC'

end
```

Even tried two different versions of Rails 3 with no luck...

Comment: Can you show the full source of `show.html.erb` please? Based on the error it looks like you're missing an `end` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure but based on the code you supplied from the view and the error message, you probably forgot to close the form_for with end:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_area :content %>
<% end %>
```

Edit:

Looking at your model I actually managed to reproduce your problem by adding a questionmark to one of my database columns.

The columns in your tables should not contain any special characters like questionmark. Rename the column approved? to approved and it should work.

Comment: I'm showing the whole code now.  I do have an end there.  Wish it was that, though!  Thanks for looking at it.  (It's driving me nuts!)

Comment: Okey, your form looks good so I think the problem lies within you Post model. Can you also supply the code for that model and include the names of the attributes in case they are reserved words or something?